# Given a text representation of a MIME message, how can I recreate the message?

Tags: python, tcp, mime-types, mime

I have a GDB core dump that contains the header and body of a MIME mutlipart/form-data request message. I need to somehow recreate the message exactly and send it to my server so that I can debug why my code is crashing.

The message is from a fairly standard form-data page. All of the Content-Types are text/plain, except for one that is image/jpeg.

The problem is that the binary part of the body has boundaries already, so I can't just extract the binary portion and generate the header automatically via built-in Python MIME code.

Again, I need to recreate the initial message exactly how it was. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "the binary part of the body has boundaries already"? `email.parser.Parser().parsestr(text)` will properly parse multipart MIME messages with multipart boundaries. Can you create a simple example and upload it somewhere? Or show the code that you used that didn't work, and a traceback (or an explanation of where it failed, if it wasn't an exception)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the initial message exactly how it was"? It presumably originally was a bunch of separate files, and then some kind of thing in some kind of internal format used by a web browser (or Python's `email.mime` library, or some PHP library, or whatever), and then it was the RFC2822 text MIME enclosure. The last one is exactly what you already have; the previous ones aren't meaningful.

Comment: Let me try a different question: How, precisely, does the data you have differ from the data you want?

Comment: Okay, so I used GDB to create a binary dump of the body. I used the following python script initially: `code` import requests

# ...
# filepath = 'C:\binbin'
url = 'http://9.19.145.251:8080'
files = {'file': ('userfile', open('binbin', 'rb'))}
data = {'account_id': 'root'}
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
res = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers=headers) `code`. The problem is that the binary dump isn't the raw data; it already has headers and boundaries from when it was captured.

Answer (score 0):

I might use [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ nc -q 5 serverhost 80 < message_file.txt
```

Comment: Please read the question more carefully. I can't personally send the MIME message -- I only have a GDB core dump that contains it. So, I have the original header and body of the message, both in text format. I need to take these and generate/send a new message that's exactly the same. I already know how to capture traffic with TCPDump. Also, I can't find a single reference to the "-q" option in Netcat.

Comment: Thank you, @user1765354. I did read the message very carefully. I read that the GDB core image "contains the header and body of a MIME mutlipart/form-data request message." If you have the headers and the body, what more do you need?

Comment: From my ubuntu 12.04 system's `man nc` man page: "**-q** after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If `seconds` is negative, wait forever."